# Using execute for visual command in vim

Tags: vim

I know this must be something simple.

Why does `vnoremap <leader>rl di[<esc>pa]` wrap selected text in brackets, but:

```
vnoremap <leader>rl :call VisAddRefLink()<CR>

function! VisAddRefLink()
    execute "normal! di[\<esc>pa]"
endfunction
```

doesn't?!

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
vnoremap <leader>rl :<C-u>call VisAddRefLink()<CR>

function! VisAddRefLink()
    execute "normal! gvdi[\<esc>pa]"
endfunction
```

The `<C-u>` in front of the `call` avoids that the mapping inserts the `'<,'>` visual range in front of it; we want the function called only one time, not once for every line in the range.

Inside the function, we need to re-establish the visual selection first before operating on it; the `gv` does that.

Comment: Likewise, you could use `<esc>:` instead of `:<C-u>` as in the other example. I probably overcomplicated things! :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your function handle a range. One way of accomplishing this would be like this:

```
vnoremap <leader>rl :call VisAddRefLink()<CR>

function! VisAddRefLink() range
   exe a:firstline . "normal! ^i["
   exe a:lastline . "normal! $a]"
endfunction
```

The reason your example isn't working is because the exe doesn't operate on a visual selection per say. For example, try visually selection something and then doing `:norm d`. You'll notice it doesn't delete. If you add a range to your function like `:help function-range-example` it helps with visual selections by operating in a similar fashion (line by line). However, it still isn't a true visual selection. The range addition does allow you the `a:firstline` and `a:lastline` variables though, which can be used to accomplish this. You can also accomplish this with a single like in this manner:

```
vnoremap <leader>rl <esc>:norm! '<^x2Phr['>$x2pr]<cr>
```

This first uses `<esc>` to end the visual selection. Then it executes a normal command that will only run once. If the visual selection was left then it would run once for each line in the visual selection. Once it's run once it

`'<^` jumps to the first line of the visual selection and to the first non-blank space on that line.

`x2Phr[` deletes that character, pastes it twice in front, moves to the left so we're over the new character, and replaces it with the opening [

`'>$` move to the last character on the last line of the visual selection

`x2pr]` same as before but in the opposite direction

As usual, there's more than one way to skin a cat, especially with vimscript. As you learn more you see a lot of possibilities for accomplishing things.

Comment: Thanks very much for your input Conner, it works, but I've used Ingo's  solution as it seems a little simpler.